# How can I sort divs with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, electron

I would like to sort a few divs in ascending order based on their data-id. How can I do that?

```
<div class="container" data-id="1000">
  <div id="H1"></div>
  <div id="sub">sub 1</div>
  <div id="sub">sub 2</div>
</div>

<div class="container" data-id="3000">
  <div id="H1"></div>
  <div id="sub"></div>
  <div id="sub"></div>
</div>

<div class="container" data-id="2000">
  <div id="H1"></div>
  <div id="sub"></div>
  <div id="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: More info would help. For example, where is the `chapName` variable coming from?

Comment: **You cannot have any given `id` value more than once per page. `id` must be unique at all times!**

Comment: Also `container` is an invalid attribute name on `div` elements. **This makes your HTML invalid**.

Comment: Ehmm... 'div container' needs to be ```div id``` :-D

Comment: Chapname is a variable I get out of a database. Like this: ```db.each("SELECT DISTINCT chapname FROM Chapters ORDER BY chaporder", function(err,chapters) 
    { 
      if (err) 
      {console.log('ERROR!', err);}   
    
      else {
      // create variable
      let chapname = [];
      // push callback 'chapters' into variable 'chapname'
      chapname.push(chapters.chapname);
      // console.log(row);   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem a while ago:

```
function sortOut() {

    // get the classname chapcontainer
    var classname = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

    // create a variable and put the classes it into an array. 
    var divs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; ++i) {
        divs.push(classname[i]);
    }

    // Sort the divs based on data-id. 
    divs.sort(function(a, b) {
        return +a.getAttribute("data-id") - +b.getAttribute("data-id");
    });
};
```

divs.sort does the trick. More info about this function can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp